# Bash script to copy a folder's contents and overwrite destination?

Tags: bash

I'm just barely familiar with bash scripts, and am trying to achieve being able to specify a source location (a directory with files / sub-directories) and a list of multiple destination directories, along with a list of files / directories from the source to exclude when copying & replacing.

The script should loop through each destination location, copy the files from the source and replace them in the destination location, excluding any files / directories listed in the script to skip.

In PHP it would be something like:

```
$source = '/home/user1/public_html';
$destinations = array(
    'user2',
    'user3',
    'user4'
);
$exclude = array(
    '/uploads/custom',
    '/config/conf.php'
);
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    $dir = '/home/' .$destination. '/public_html';
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        exec('cp -R ' .$source. '/* ' .$dir);
        // and somehow exclude overwriting any files / directories matching what's in the $exclude array
    }
}
```

So, my question is, how would a bash script with similar functionality be written?

Comment: do u want copy from /home/user1/public_html to another directory or 2 another directory ?

Comment: Copy the files from /home/user1/public_html (source) to /home/user2/public_html, /home/user3/public_html and /home/user4/public_html (the destinations), for example.

Comment: you use for loop` for ((i=1;i<5;i++)); do cp -R /home/user$i/public_html/*  /tmp/user$i/* ; done;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
    if [[ -d "$line" ]]; then
        rsync -rv --exclude-from "exclude.txt" /home/source/public_html/ "$line"
    else
        echo "Directory $line does not exist!"
    fi
done < "accounts.txt"
```

This reads from a file called "accounts.txt" that has all the destination account directories in it, one per line. Ex:

```
/home/user1/public_html
/home/myblog/public_html
```

It loops through each one, and if the directory exists, it copies the files from /home/source/public_html to the destination. It also reads from a file called "exclude.txt" that includes, one per line, any files or directories to exclude. Ex:

```
.git
/uploads/custom
/config/conf.php
```